# Is it possible to continuing running JavaScript code after a redirect?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, api

So, on my website, a user types in a subject they want the gist of, then after searching, it redirects them to a Wikipedia API displaying the general idea of the subject. However, there's a bunch of information about the API that gets in the way on the webpage, so I need to use JavaScript to get rid of that excess stuff.

Unfortunately, after changing webpages, it seems I can't run any more code from my website.
Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iframe, like so:

```
<iframe id="wikipedia-stuff">
</iframe>
```

And populate it like so:

```
 <script>
 document.getElementById("wikipedia-stuff").src = "http://wikipedia.stuff";
 </script>
```

The wikipedia stuff would be in the iframe, and your code would still be running.

Comment: Header on the API is set to SAMEORIGIN, so I can't do it.